# How to add music file to C program in linux? do I have to download any extra codec? or Gstreamer is enough?

Tags: c

I want to add music file to my C program, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Gstreamer is fine, if you use one of the codecs Gstreamer has installed. Vorbis is usually a good choice.